# Delete 30k+ objects

Tags: mesh, objects, outliner

while trying to create some trees together with particles I somehow managed to create 30-50.000 singular objects, of which I have deleted 5000 in the last hour, but I am still wondering if there is a quicker way, especially since Blender is understandably extremely slow right now, every click takes a minute or two before being applied. 
Right now I use the outlined to select via mouse click and shift multiple objects, but it takes a little eternity to scroll down a few thousand objects for selection. 
Any ideas are highly welcome.

Comment: Your question can be more clearly posed with a small amount of your effort. Your question would be clearer with a screen capture showing the outliner.  Python Scripts can delete objects by name.  Thus you can loop through all object names and delete names with a particular pattern.  Maker sure you create a backup of your valuable work.

Comment: Instead of deleting you can try to *Append* necessary objects to a new blend-file

Comment: If these objects have a common parent you can select the parent.  Then select the children by the menu choice (not multiple clicks).  Then delete.  The outliner it select can filter objects by name and then you can delete.  No Script perhaps.

Comment: You can also just start  a new file or portion and recreate your work with perhaps zero mistakes since you are more practiced now in this area.  Your have mentioned your computer is slow.  You can stop the on screen render of objects in the outliner.  If Blender is displaying close to zero objects it will be faster. Then just turn on a few critical ones to view and choose a form of deletion or new creation.

Comment: In the Outliner header there is a "search" filter box, There type in the  base name of the objects you want to delete, Tree for example. This will find and display in the outliner all and Only objects with Tree in their name. Left click in the Outliner then hit the A key to select them All. All the Trees will be selected in the 3D worlspace. Mouse over the 3D workspace and X key to Delete all those Trees.

Comment: Appending didn't work completely, but after some fiddling selecting all with A finally worked and deleting everything at once took Blender like an hour or something, but it worked, thanks a lot for all the suggestions! :)